# Get object position in a three.js scene dynamically

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to [threejs](https://threejs.org).

I have scene with an object in it which we can move around the scene on all the XYZ Axis using [TransformControls.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js).

When I translate/move the object inside the scene using mouse click and drag on any of the axis (i.e X,Y,Z). I want to get the updated X,Y,Z position co-ordinates of that particular object inside the scene.

I use `mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );` to set position of the object prior rendering the scene, But I am not able to find how to get the dynamic position of an object inside a scene.

Eventually I want to save the updated position co-ordinates after the transform operation and re-render the scene with the object at the updated position co-ordinates when the user comes back to the page or does a page refresh.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: `mesh.position` is a `Vector3` which is the local position of the mesh. It looks like TransformControls updates this vector, so you should be able to get the new position from `mesh.position` after the transform is complete. Is this what you're tying to do, or is `mesh.position` not being updated after the transformation?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. When I do `console.log(mesh.position.x + ','  + mesh.position.y + ',' + mesh.position.z)` after calling `THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`  I get the output as `0,0,0` So yes mesh.position is not getting updated after I move the object inside the scene.

Comment: One more question: Which version of `three.js` are you using?

Comment: I am using `three.js R73`

Comment: For the record, r73 is quite old. The current version is r84. I understand if you have limitations which prevent you from upgrading to the latest version, but it is highly recommended.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider upgrading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`THREE.TransformControls` requires a few steps to use.

1. Create your THREE.TransformControls object
2. Add it to your scene
3. Attach it to the object you wish to manipulate

```js
var xformControl = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
scene.add(xformControls);
// assuming you add "myObj" to your scene...
xformControl.attach(myObj);
// and then later...
xformControl.detatch();
```

Attaching the control to an object will insert a manipulation "gizmo" into the scene. Dragging the various parts of the gizmo will perform different kinds of transformations. After you are done transforming the part with the gizmo, checking `mesh.position` should reflect the new position.

**Additional information for clarity:**

The position of the object will not be updated until you use the "gizmo"  to move it. Example:

1. Your object is in the scene at (10, 10, 10)
2. `xformControl.attach(yourObject)`
3. The "gizmo" is created at (10, 10, 10)
4. Your object remains at (10, 10, 10)
5. Use the "gizmo" to translate the object in +Y direction
6. Your object will now have an updated position
7. `console.log(yourObject.position.y > 10); // true`

Comment: Try reading the position of xformcontrols and use the three.js inspector. It will let you visually inspect all objects, hierarchy and transforms and prevent endless searches.

Comment: Thank you @TheJim01 for the detailed instructions to use `Three.TransformControls`. I have the same code. You are spot on! After Debugging I found `mesh.position` does have the updated position. but Just doing a `console.log(mesh.position.x)` after `xformControl.attach(myObj);` does not get me the updated position.

Comment: Thank you @Hacky for suggesting the cool chrome extension [three.js inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/threejs-inspector/dnhjfclbfhcbcdfpjaeacomhbdfjbebi) . Yes even the position of `xformcontrols` is updated when I check using the inspector but `console.log(xformcontrols.position.x)` still does not work.

Comment: @TaherJodhpurwala `xformCtonrol.attach(myObj)` will _not_ give you an updated position. The "gizmo" is created at the same location as your object, and the object remains where it was in the scene. It does not update until you use the "gizmo" to transform the object.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle @TheJim01

Comment: @Aashajoney This three.js example should serve the same purpose: https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html

Answer (score 3):

I might be too late, but you can get the updated value by using TransformControls' `objectChange` event.

Example code:

```
const transformControls = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

transformControls.addEventListener('objectChange', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.object.position.x);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

first answer is not correct, it should be:

```js
onst transformControls = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

transformControls.addEventListener('objectChange', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.object.position.x);
})
```